# How to create a dropdownmenu using compose and monogDb?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose

I have been trying a while now to figure out how to make a dropdownmenu using jetpack compose and mongoDb. It would be a simple dropdownmenu with 3 options and whatever the user picks will be registred into monog database. If the user changes their option, the information will be updated in mongodb as well. How can I achieve this feature? Appreciate any feedback!

A more simple dropdownmenu would also work.

Basic dropdownmenu: https://gyazo.com/9b9901b4f03ec0b01b5869b5cfaffd86

```
DropDownMenu:

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AnimalLargeDropdownMenu(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    label: String,
    notSetLabel: String? = null,
    onItemClicked: () -> String,
    items: RealmList<String>,
    selectedIndex: Int = -1,
    onItemSelected: (index: Int, item: String) -> Unit,
    selectedItemToString: (String) -> String = { it },
    drawItem: @Composable (String, Boolean, Boolean, () -> Unit) -> Unit = { item, selected, itemEnabled, onClick ->
        AnimalLargeDropdownMenuItem(
            text = item,
            selected = selected,
            enabled = itemEnabled,
            onClick = onClick,
        )
    },
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(modifier = modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            label = { Text(label) },
            value = items.getOrNull(selectedIndex)?.let { selectedItemToString(it) } ?: "",
            enabled = enabled,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
            },
            onValueChange = { },
            readOnly = true,
        )

        // Transparent clickable surface on top of OutlinedTextField
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = 8.dp)
                .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.extraSmall)
                .clickable(enabled = enabled) { expanded = true },
            color = Color.Transparent,
        ) {}
    }

    if (expanded) {
        Dialog(
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            Surface(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
            ) {
                val listState = rememberLazyListState()
                if (selectedIndex > -1) {
                    LaunchedEffect("ScrollToSelected") {
                        listState.scrollToItem(index = selectedIndex)
                    }
                }

                LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), state = listState) {
                    if (notSetLabel != null) {
                        item {
                            AnimalLargeDropdownMenuItem(
                                text = notSetLabel,
                                selected = false,
                                enabled = false,
                                onClick = { onItemClicked.invoke()},
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->
                        val selectedItem = index == selectedIndex
                        drawItem(
                            item,
                            selectedItem,
                            true
                        ) {
                            onItemSelected(index, item)
                            expanded = false
                        }

                        if (index < items.lastIndex) {
                            Divider(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AnimalLargeDropdownMenuItem(
    text: String,
    selected: Boolean,
    enabled: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val contentColor = when {
        !enabled -> MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = DefaultAlpha)
        selected -> MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.copy(alpha = DefaultAlpha)
        else -> MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = DefaultAlpha)
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides contentColor) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(enabled) { onClick() }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from your question it's unclear what exactly doesn't work as you expect. Also a lot of code seems to be missing. Please remove all unrelated code and reduce it to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this a simple dropdown with an update function, your service layer should integrate with mongoDb or any other data base

```
@Composable
fun YourScreen() {
 
    val options = remember { mutableStateListOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3") }

    // Store the selected index
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }

    fun updateMongoDB(selectedIndex: Int) {
        val selectedOption = options.getOrNull(selectedIndex)
        if (selectedOption != null) {
            // Update Database
        }
    }

    // Composable dropdown menu
    AnimalLargeDropdownMenu(
        label = "Select an option",
        items = options,
        selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
        onItemSelected = { index, _ ->
            selectedIndex = index
            updateMongoDB(index)
        }
    )
}
```